Trouble mounting tutor-mfe: frontend-app-authoring
I have been trying to mount frontend-app-authoring to my tutor. Here is what I have done:

Cloned frontend-app-authoring to my local machine and made a very basic change to the code. I made the background of the mfe ‘black’ and saved the code.
I then ran the tutor’s mounting command which successfully mounted the cloned repo to tutor. I then ran tutor dev launch but the changes I made to the code i.e., made background black isn’t being reflected.
When this didn’t work, I also tried running the authoring mfe locally and every other service (cms, lms, mfe) in the container. The authoring mfe runs on port 2001 but I get some authentication error which doesn’t let me go into the studio.

For further context, I have the updated tutor-mfe version 18.1.0 where a bug regarding the naming convention was fixed
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
